# make doesn't see changes?

Tags: makefile

Scenario 1:

I checked out a project, and made some changes to a source file, and did make, and make sees the changes.

Scenario 2:

I checked out the project again to different directory (some reasons), copied the modified source file here, and did make and nothing happens, if I run the program, I don't see my changes, make doesn't see that I made change to this source file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`make` uses the timestamps of the files to determine what to build.

Perhaps your version-control system is checking all files out with the current time. When you copy your source over, it has a time in the past, making `make` think that the object file (presumably in your checkout) is newer than your source.

If that's the case, you can use `touch` to set the timestamp of a file to now.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to existing answers:

To touch the targets, you can use the `-t` or `--touch` option of make. This option will not make the target but just touch it so that the next time you invoke `make`, the target will be made.

Alternatively you can use the `-B` or `--always-make` option which will unconditionally make the target irrespective of the modification of it's dependent(s).

Answer (score 0):

okay, I just touched the copied (modified) source and now make recognizes the changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you used `cp` to copy files options `-a --archive -p --preserve` will preserve the timestamp. That is not what you want!

Add option `--no-preserve=timestamps`

```
cp [options] --no-preserve=timestamps .....
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your .PHONY tags and they are correct